# How do I get WebStorm to display more detailed information in console?

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I'm currently doing a learning project in WebStorm. I'm using the "JetBrains IDE Support" plugin for Chrome to function as a liveserver for testing.

I'm running the following JS code:

```
return item.classList.contains('meal-info')
```

In Chrome Dev Tools I'm getting 
[image]

but in WebStorm's console I'm only getting 
[image]

How do I get WebStorm to display the full content? The purpose of overriding using Chrome Dev Tools and having it rerouted to WebStorm's console seems useless if it's going to be missing critical data I need. In this example I needed it to contain `data-mealid` as well, but it only displayed simplified information.

Comment: Legit, LazyOne, you're something else.  You spent the time capitalizing the name of the program and crossed out me saying thank you? Is your ego that fragile that you need that empowerment to edit out a thank you to feel important?

Comment: Good question. I cannot find the exact link where I did read that (long time ago, like 5 or 6 years back), can only find this post right now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts . But yes, when I'm editing posts I'm pretty much always removing ending "Thanks", "Thank you"; not for the reason you have described.